# Output of function using np.reciprocal changes based on print or further (unrelated) calculations

Tags: python, numpy

Whilst computing SVD  I encountered strange behaviour in relation to np.reciprocal. Under certain conditions (i.e. additional steps on an unrelated variable or printing a variable) the output changes for some reason.

The following is a simplified version of the code.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig
from math import sqrt

def ComputeSVD(A):
    m, n = A.shape
    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = eig(A.T @ A)

    Sigma = np.zeros((m,n))
    np.fill_diagonal(Sigma, np.sqrt(eigenvalues))
    print(Sigma)

    U = np.zeros((m,m))
    for i in range(len(eigenvalues)):
         U[:,i] =  A @ (eigenvectors[:,i]) 

    return Sigma


def PseudoInverse(A):
    S = ComputeSVD(A)
    S_inv = np.reciprocal(S, where= (S != 0))
    return S_inv

A = np.array([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 4.0, 9.0]])
print(PseudoInverse(A))
```

The output is incorrect for the non-diagonal entries:

```
[[10.64956309  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          1.2507034   0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.15015641]]
[[ 0.09390057 -0.74904542  0.64830637]
 [-0.34457359  0.79955008 -0.73997748]
 [-0.92878374  0.32438956  6.65972239]]
```

However when removing the parts computing related to **U**

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig
from math import sqrt

def ComputeSVD(A):
    m, n = A.shape
    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = eig(A.T @ A)

    Sigma = np.zeros((m,n))
    np.fill_diagonal(Sigma, np.sqrt(eigenvalues))
    print(Sigma)

    return (Sigma) 


def PseudoInverse(A): #same as before

A = np.array([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 4.0, 9.0]])
print(PseudoInverse(A))
```

Now the Output is correct:

```
[[10.64956309  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          1.2507034   0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.15015641]]
[[0.09390057 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.79955008 0.        ]
 [0.         0.         6.65972239]]
```

Even stranger is that when we leave the parts relating to **U** but, before we invert the non-zero entries we, print(S) the issue is again rectified.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig
from math import sqrt

def ComputeSVD(A): #Same as first time

def PseudoInverse(A):
    S = ComputeSVD(A)
    print(S)
    S_inv = np.reciprocal(S, where= (S != 0))
    return S_inv

A = np.array([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 4.0, 9.0]])
print(PseudoInverse(A))
```

Now the correct output is produced again. (see the second output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
 S_inv = np.reciprocal(S, where=(S != 0))
```

creates an uninitialized array and fills the entries where the condition `S != 0` is `True` with reciprocals of the corresponding elements of `S`. All other elements are left unchanged, so they may be zeroes, but may also have some random values. In order to fix this, use the `out` argument to initialize an array where the result will be stored:

```
 S_inv = np.reciprocal(S, where=(S != 0), out=np.zeros_like(S))
```

Comment: Some how `ufunc` with a `where` but no `out` need a warning if not an error message.